# Convert this to Ruby 1.9 Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following in the old syntax:

```
render json: [@note.to_json(:include => { :contact => { :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]}}, only: :body)], status: :created, location: [@contact, @note]
```

How would I do this in the new 1.9 hash syntax? I've tried plenty of different ways but can't seem to understand the syntax.  On a side note, I find it rather confusing.

Edit: Actually realized I'm already mixing it in with the json: call.  Bah!  Hate going between to two.

Comment: Do you still have any of your latest attempts in code we could see?

Comment: There is no *old* syntax, there is just a new syntax available for a limited set of Hash literals. There's nothing wrong with using `=>` and in fact you have to use it if your keys are not symbols or if they're symbols like `:$in` or `:'this.that'`.

Comment: I've tried plenty of variations, but it keeps throwing up errors when I include {}.  Seems that the nesting of hashes in there causes confusion and it's really difficult to read in my opinion.  Thanks, mu.  I hate that I have to go between the two, but would really not enjoy seeing the new optional syntax in future code releases and not be used to seeing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure where the trouble is, but it converts pretty simply to this:

```
render json: [@note.to_json(include: { contact: { except: [:created_at, :updated_at]}}, only: :body)], status: :created, location: [@contact, @note]
```

As an aside, stringing so many nested structures together on one line is bound to be confusing. Break it down so it's readable (and writable).

Answer (score 1):

Your example works fine. Only need to change a few more keys

```
require 'pp'
pp json: [
    {
      include: { 
        contact: { 
          except: [:created_at, :updated_at]
        }
      },
      only: :body
    }
  ], 
  status: :created, 
  location: %w[contact note]
```

So, aside from some slight changes to get around objects I don't have access to (@contact and @note) the only ones I changed were

```
:include => { :contact => { :except =>
```

to

```
include: { contact: { except:
```

Also, you might look into using [rabl](http://rubygems.org/gems/rabl) for this sort of thing.